# Torquebox - project is not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrubyonrails, ubuntu-12.10, torquebox

I have installed:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- jruby 1.7.3
- ruby 2
- rails 3.2.13
- RubyMine 5
- DB2 C-Express

I have create a sample application and connected it correctly to the database - I know this because I have successfully executed the scaffold and migrate commands and check that the tables are created.

Then I have run the following commands in order to deploy my application with torquebox 2.0:

```
torquebox deploy
torquebox run
```

I have run these commands in my project folder and as a result on localhost:8080 I am seeing rails start page. I have the following issues:

1. Clicking on "About your application’s environment" tab I am getting the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException:
>   (NameError) cannot link Java class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver, probable
>   missing dependency: Could not initialize class
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
>     org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doRack(RackFilter.java:117)
>     org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:101)
>     org.torquebox.web.servlet.RackFilter.doFilter(RackFilter.java:72)
>     org.torquebox.web.servlet.SendfileFilter.doFilter(SendfileFilter.java:49)
>     org.torquebox.web.servlet.SendfileFilter.doFilter(SendfileFilter.java:33)

I believe this is because the torque box is not able to find the driver. But why as it is vissible in my rails application and I successfully created/migrate tables from it using the terminal? Should I put the driver somewhere else,too?

1. Then I the torque box [documentation](http://torquebox.org/builds/getting-started/first-steps.html#first-steps-rvm) is said:

> Changes to your Rails application show up immediately in the browser,
>   as expected. When you're done, press CTRL+C in the terminal to stop
>   TorqueBox before continuing with the next steps.

But that's exactly what I have had to do in order to refresh the content of the page. I have changed my gem file and database.yml file but refreshing the page did not reflect this. After I have stop the server and start it again it shows something different.

Could you advise or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: not all changes show up immediately, some changes require restarting the process - did you run `bundle install` after updating your Gemfile? you will definitely need to restart (also changes to database.yml require a restart)

Comment: Yes, I have run bundle install several times during the changes. Unfortunately, I am not able to confirm this is happing again because I can't fix the torque box error described above.

Answer (score 1):

Without restarting the Torquebox server your can redeploy the knob with `touch` just run

```
touch $TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss/standalone/deployments/your_apps-knob.yml.deployed
```

this way you don't have to restart whole JBOSS server.[Deployment via descriptor](http://torquebox.org/documentation/3.0.1/deployment.html#deployment-via-descriptor)

For production setups you can use Capistrano [Torquebox Capistrano support](http://torquebox.org/documentation/3.0.1/capistrano-support.html)